# How Do I Set Unique, Descriptive Hostnames for AWS Auto Scaled Instances?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, scale

My ASG assigns scaled nodes the **aws:autoscaling:groupName** to each **Instance Name**.
This yields multiple instances with the same **Instance Name**.

For example:

| Instance Name | Instance ID |
| --- | --- |
| dev-test-my-ASG | i-05w50iy3g34co7uea |
| dev-test-my-ASG | i-0mri5p3or7k6dxxv5 |
| dev-test-my-ASG | i-0ak1ws9m049nt00b5 |
| dev-test-my-ASG | i-0408tzorvsg5l74zq |
| dev-test-my-ASG | i-0qw480y71ddns2vsv |
| dev-test-my-ASG | i-0y4c2t7zv5jytt7c7 |

To avoid naming collisions, these scaled instances default to **IP name** for **Hostname type**.

For example:

| Hostname | Instance ID |
| --- | --- |
| ip-192-168-10-123.ec2.internal | i-05w50iy3g34co7uea |
| ip-192-168-10-3.ec2.internal | i-05w50iy3g34co7uea |
| ip-192-168-10-2.ec2.internal | i-0mri5p3or7k6dxxv5 |
| ip-192-168-10-23.ec2.internal | i-0ak1ws9m049nt00b5 |
| ip-192-168-10-231.ec2.internal | i-0408tzorvsg5l74zq |
| ip-192-168-10-213.ec2.internal | i-0qw480y71ddns2vsv |
| ip-192-168-10-26.ec2.internal | i-0y4c2t7zv5jytt7c7 |

How can I configure my launch template to provide unique hostnames for the auto-scaled EC2 instances, so that they include the ASG name in the hostname without defaulting to the IP address.

For example:

- dev-test-my-ASG-ip-192-168-10-123.ec2.internal (A combination of ASG and IP Address)
- dev-test-my-ASG-1728343 (A combination of ASG and Random Hash)

I expect a method to create unique, descriptive names for the scaled nodes.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. What are you trying to achieve by giving them unique names?

Comment: You can customize the name indirectly (e.g. via a lambda), but not the hostname as far as I know

Comment: I installed Elastic Metricbeat on these nodes.  By default, Metricbeat picks up the Hostname, but not the tags.  I want a simple way to associate an ASG with a scaled instance.  If I can get info in the hostname, I'm done.  If not, I need to upgrade boto, and then play with Environment Vars/ User Scripts or Lambda functions to get the info I need.  Right now it defaults to the ASG name for each new scaled instance, and then must use the IP address for host name.  If I can use {ASG}-{IP} then I suspect it will pick up this unique, descriptive name.

Comment: You already said Metricbeat only looks at hostnames, not tags, so why are you asking how to fix the tags? Instance Name is a tag, it is not a DNS hostname. You later ask "How can I configure my launch template to provide unique hostnames" but hostnames are actual DNS names within the VPC, which is totally different from Instance Name, which is just a tag.

Comment: So to clarify is the actual hostname in the OS that you want to change or the DNS name that AWS assigns? Also is this Amazon Linux 2/2023?

Comment: @Ajay - thank you for your thoughtful question.  I would like to change the hostname.  For example, if I CURL 169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/hostname I will see dev-test-my-ASG-ip-192-168-10-123.ec2.internal.   For the second part: NAME="Amazon Linux"
VERSION="2"
ID="amzn"
ID_LIKE="centos rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="2"
PRETTY_NAME="Amazon Linux 2"
ANSI_COLOR="0;33"
CPE_NAME="cpe:2.3:o:amazon:amazon_linux:2"
HOME_URL="https://amazonlinux.com/"

Comment: Ok, so you can change the hostname in the OS, thats not a problem - but it sounds like you ALSO want the instance meta-data to also be updated too?

Comment: @Ajay TBH - if I can change the hostname, that will answer it!

Comment: OK, have you looked at: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/set-hostname.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the hostname in the OS, you can follow this [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/set-hostname.html)

test if this works with your other software.

If you are looking to do this for an Auto Scaling Group, I would use something like the USERDATA section of the EC2 template and have something like the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "preserve_hostname: true">>/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg
MY_HOSTNAME=dev-test-my-ASG-$RANDOM    
hostnamectl set-hostname $MY_HOSTNAME
echo "HOSTNAME=$MY_HOSTNAME">>/etc/sysconfig/network
echo "127.0.0.1   $MY_HOSTNAME $MY_HOSTNAME.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4">/etc/hosts
echo "::1         localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6">>/etc/hosts
```

May have to issue a reboot command at the end of this, but see if it works without it.